Ubuntu Budgie Window / UI freezing issues
I am using Ubuntu Budgie (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) Version 10.6.1 with X11.
Laptop is an old Dell G15 with intel 7 8th and an Nvidia 1050 GPU.
Occasionally, icons in the plank toolbar and the systems toolbar are replaced with white rectangles.
Also, the close and minimize buttons on windows disappear.
Then, apps start to freeze, until the system completely misbehaves and I need to shutdown via pressing the reset button.
I already checked disk (health is reported as ok) and RAM (Memtest 86+ for 2.5 hours, everything is fine).
Does Anyone get an idea what might cause this issue and what logfile to look at to narrow down the source?
EDIT:
I re-run memtest for about 8 hours in total now, no errors occurred. I used fsck to check if there are any file system corruptions, but everything is clean. Furthermore, I used smartmontools to check the health of the disk again, several times using the long test, but everything is fine. Is it possible that this freezing is related to a hardware issue with the mainboard? Do you have any suggestions how to find the source of this issue?
